# Is there a better way to write multiple Nota Bene? i.e "n.b., n.b.b." e.t.c

Tags: writing-style, latin

What is the preferred way to write:

> n.b. Thing.
> n.b. Related thing #2.

Can you use an approach similar to P.S.?:

> p.s (post-scriptum)
> p.p.s (postquam-post-scriptum)

Or, should it be something like:

> n.b. Thing.
>
> related thing #2

Comment: If clarity is what you're aiming for, try a format like: NB (1):, NB (2):, NB (3): etc.

Comment: N.B.B. is right out, _nota bene bene_ sounds... Italian, but not Latin or English.

Comment: _Nota bene_ simply means "note well". It's an imperative and there are no nouns or pronouns. Hence there is no plural for anything that is to be noted. **N.B:** with a numbered list following will do.

Comment: My understanding was that "N.B." meant "note well", meaning "this is important!" and drawing particular attention to what would otherwise be a unobtrusive footnote.  If you have a bunch of these they stop being so special and just become ordinary footnotes.

Comment: Yeah, nice answer. I guess it's like someone who uses ASAP in every email which reduces the importance of the first.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to write *“nota bene”* is ***Please Note:***.

Comment: And for the second thing that needs to be noted, **Please Note As Well:**?

Comment: @oerk Just use whatever makes sense. No reason to use Latin here, no matter who you stack it.

Comment: Ah, but _quidquid Latine dictum sit altum videtur_!

Comment: @oerkelens *Sed linguae mortuorum nihil dicunt.*

Comment: *Nota Bene* sounds more authoritative, like a warning: Ignore at your own peril. It's no worse than using *status quo*, *sine qua non*, *foie gras* or *folie à deux* .